# Servlet JSON response ENCODING issue For "="

Tags: java, json, servlets, gson, response

I have simple JSON Object as follows :

```
{"status":"Success","action":"Redirect","sessionid":6467349943156736,"url":"https://myapplicationing.com/go?id=1000"}
```

i have created JSON as follows:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("status", "Success");
json.put("action", "Redirect");
json.put("sessionid", "6467349943156736");
json.put("url", "https://myapplicationing.com/go?id=1000");
```

when i write this json as response

```
resp.setContentType("application/json");        
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        try {
//           json.write(resp.getWriter());//[tried]
//          Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
            resp.getWriter().println(json.toString());
//          resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(json));//[TRIED]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it is still giving me JSON string as follows :

```
{"status":"Success","action":"Redirect","sessionid":6467349943156736,"url":"https://myapplicationing.com/go?id\u003d1000"}
```

Here why it is `ENCODING` JSON String.
It is replacing "=" to "\u003d".

I have tried  this one :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(json));
```

But not working. Any Solution on this.

Comment: You don't care (except for readability); `"a\u003db"` and `"a=b"` are the exact, same, JSON strings.

Comment: but this response sending to another app and that app just opens up a request in browser but it not opening correctly on some browser and  some it is working

Comment: Then it is a bug in the remote applications which don't decode JSON Strings correctly; you should report that to them

Comment: ohhh !!! so no work around for me to handle this ?

Comment: No idea... I use Jackson, not Gson...

Comment: @fge can you past your response code ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: can you give any sample for Jackson

Comment: I can, of course, but first of all try and build your `Gson` with `new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create()` to see if that solves the problem. The Javadoc says that Gson escapes HTML chars by default, which imnsho it shouldn't.

Comment: yes i have tried that but i got the same output

Comment: Uhm, that is really strange. Is your JSON issued from a serialized object?

Comment: i dont think so if then how it will work on some machine browser and on some machine browser not

Comment: OK, I'll rephrase: where does the JSON you send come from to start with?

Comment: i have created JSON in my servlet ..

Comment: Yes, but _how_? Did you do it by hand using `JsonElement`? Did you serialize an instance of some class?

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
and use json.put("url","https://myapplicationing.com/go?id=1000");

Comment: Uh, what version of Gson is that? In 2.2.4 there is no `.put()` method on `JsonObject`. Please paste the full JSON generation code in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50125/discussion-between-swap-l-and-fge)

Comment: Uh, why did you do this -- `json.put("url", "https://myapplicationing.com/go?id\u003d1000");` -- if you want the `=` to be clear text?

Comment: @HotLicks ohh sorry that was by mistek

Comment: try to use : `String s = "some text";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); `

Comment: @erhan i dint get you ..

Comment: I mean you can escape characters to converting them byte to string ( unicode to string) or string to byte.

Comment: yes but how i can send there resopnse in JSON then because my client accept format is JSON

Comment: What container are you using? This really shouldn't be happening and I can't reproduce it. Are you sure you aren't adding to your `JSONObject` through some other value than a `String` literal? Give us a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

`\u003d` is the unicode represention of `=`. It can be converted back to `=` when parsing the JSON.

Have a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html to convert unicode characters to normal string.

Comment: Yes but i dont want to send JSON like that. How can send without this.

Comment: When you are sending JSON over a network, they have to be encoded in some format and unicode is the most used and preferred format. I have not seen a situation where unicode encoding is creating a trouble. Almost all applications that handle JSON have the functionality to handle unicode encoding.

Comment: @anirudh this is not the problem here; the problem is a client bug. The JSON representation sent by the OP is perfectly valid, and if the client did its job properly, it would decode JSON String `"a\u003db"` into string `a=b` -- except some of the OP's buggy clients don't.

Comment: okay, so then the client's code has to be changed right?? No fix is needed here right??

Comment: @anirudh heh, easier said than done, as always... If this were easy, Excel wouldn't require a BOM to read UTF-8 encoded CSVs anymore ;)